# AWK: Nested Conditional Subset of Rows without Headers

Tags: awk

I have a pretty specific question, and have been able to find lots on conditional subsetting using awk but none that lends enough explicit code for me to generalize to my situation. I have a file 'keys' and a file 'features' both **without headers**. The 'keys' table contains two variables, KEY and GROUP (1st and second columns, respectively), toy example below.

```
    1          GROUP0
    2          GROUP0
    3          GROUP1
    4          GROUP1
    5          GROUP2
    6          GROUP2
```

The file 'features' contains a list of features of widgets like so (ID, FEATURE, VALUE 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns, respectively).

```
    A           num_user     10
    A           KEY          4
    B           num_user     2
    B           KEY          2
    B           battery      Large
    C           num_user     10
    C           KEY          15
    D           num_user     2
    D           KEY          2
    D           battery      Small
    E           num_user     2
    E           KEY          7
    E           battery      Small
```

I am trying to select all rows for an ID which has a value of 'KEY' that is in the 'KEY' column of 'keys' for a hardcoded list of 'GROUP' values. The desired result is

```
    A           num_user     10
    A           KEY          4
    B           num_user     2
    B           KEY          2
    B           battery      Large
    D           num_user     2
    D           KEY          2
    D           battery      Small
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Gnouc if its an easy generalization it would really save me a world of hurt, trying to avoid processing queues of certain softwares.

Comment: Your desired result does not match your expanation, or I don't understand what you want.

Comment: @chaos, the file 'keys' has the distinct KEY values 1 - 6, so I want all rows for ids (A - E) in the 'features' table which have the value of 1-6 for their KEY (in the FEATURE column)... That is why we exclude the rows for C and E because they have KEY values of 15 and 7, respectively (i.e. not in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})

Comment: This is almost exactly the same question as [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136444/awk-nested-conditional-subset-of-rows). You can use the same answer, just omit the `FNR > 2` parts.

Comment: It's _exactly_ the same question, posted by the same user, just 1 day apart. Only the OP omitted to mention that they didn't have column headers in the original case. So they should've fixed the original question to say what it should've always said, rather than duplicating it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 3-pass approach with awk:

```
FNR == 1 {
        fn++        # counter for File Number, starts at 1
}

fn == 1 {
        key[$1] = 1 # first file: store keys
}

fn == 2 && $2 == "KEY" && $3 in key {
        id[$1] = 1  # second file, first pass: store id's
}

fn == 3 && $1 in id # second file, 2nd pass: print rows
```

Supposing the above is saved in `selectrows.awk`, use it like so:

```
awk -f selectrows.awk keys.txt features.txt features.txt
```

or, all on one line:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {f++}; f == 1 {k[$1]}; f == 2 && $2=="KEY" && $3 in k {i[$1]}; f == 3 && $1 in i' keys.txt features.txt features.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the key/group relations in file `keys` and your features in file `features` then below gets expected results as per the input you provided:

```
awk '{print $2}' keys | sort -u | xargs -i_group awk '{if($2=="_group")print $1}' keys | sort -u | xargs -i_key awk '{if ($3=="_key" && $2=="KEY")print $1}' features | sort -u | xargs -i_id awk '{if($1=="_id")print $0}' features
```

Its just a solution, not necessarily a good one, maybe even the worst one performance wise, but still one.

Answer (score 0):

I found this shorter solution:

```
grep -P "^\ +[`awk '$3==""{a[$1]=$2}; $2=="KEY" && $3 in a {printf "%s", $1}' \
<(cat keys features)`]" features
```

It generates a command that looks like this:

```
grep -P "^\ +[ABD]" features
```

...where the `ABD`-part in the middle is gathered by the `awk` statement